# gDEBugger crashes in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, crash, debug, opengl

I want to debug and profile some OpenGL code so I have installed the latest version of [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) on a Macbook Pro with NVidia 9400m graphics card, in Windows 8.1. When I try to run it, its splash-screen is seen first and a dialog is displayed in a fraction of a second (I cannot see it well) and its window is closed suddenly, leaving its process in the task manager (I end it). I checked the event log but there was nothing about it. I tried Windows7 and XP.SP3 compatibility modes (with admin priviledges) but nothing worked. What is the problem?

Notes for why I am trying to run this old app:

- NVidia's **NSight** says (in its specs) it needs a newer graphics card, as I understand.
- Newer versions of gDEBugger (called **CodeXL**) needs AMD Catalyst driver, so an ATI graphics card.
- I also tried [glslDevil](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/); while it is trying to run an application and populating the methods called, windows says the (OpenGL) application is not responding and closes it.

Answer (score 1):

AMD CodeXL only requires an AMD graphics card for debugging OpenCL kernels. The rest works fine on nVidia cards.
You might also want to try to find an older version of nVidia Nsight. I think support for some older cards was dropped after 3.2. Remember not to update, when it tells you a new version is available!
glslDevil is now called GLSL Debugger.